# Issue in calling web API by using HttpClient Vs. WebClient C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make a web API call by using `HttpClient` but getting `Not authorized` error. I am passing key in the header but still, it gives me this error. I can see my key in `fiddler trace`.

If I use `WebClient` then I am getting a successful response. `request` is same in both methods.

**Using HttpClient:**

```
#region HttpClient

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("apiKey", "MyKey");

    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://MyUrl", content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        deliveryManagerQuoteResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DeliveryManagerQuoteResponse>();
    }
    else
    {
        var reasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase;
        if (reasonPhrase.ToUpper() == "NOT AUTHORIZED")
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("Not authorized");
        }
    }
}

#endregion
```

**Using WebClient:**

```
#region WebClient

// Create string to hold JSON response
string jsonResponse = string.Empty;

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json");
        client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
        client.Headers.Add("apiKey", "MyKey");

        var uri = new Uri("https://MyUrl");
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

        var response = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", content);
        jsonResponse = response;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // Http Error
        if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            var statusCode = (int)webResponse.StatusCode;
            var msg = webResponse.StatusDescription;
            throw new HttpException(statusCode, msg);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

#endregion
```

Comment: First things first, [you are using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).  Secondly, are you using fiddler to see what both requests look like?  You should be able to see that the headers will look different.  Try just adding: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apiKey", "MyKey");`

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!

Comment: @maccettura, add the answer so he can mark it as accepted. ;) .

Comment: you are getting the correct json in your HttpClient example?   PostAsJsonAsync should serialize the object.  You should call JsonConvert.SerializeObject if you are using PostAsJsonAsync.

Comment: Thank you @maccettura for the link/reference to "You're using HttpClient wrong ...." valuable info that should not be lost/overlooked !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, [you are using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Secondly, are you using fiddler to see what both requests look like? You should be able to see that the headers will look different. Right now you are using the Authorization Headers which will actually do something different than you want.  All you need to do is simply add a regular 'ol header:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apiKey", "MyKey");
```

Comment: Hope people take the time to read the link "You're using HttpClient wrong ...." .  Valuable info that is not intuitive and does not directly address the problem the user was asking about.